# How to split an xml file in vb

Tags: xml, vb.net, xmlnode

I'm new with dealing with xml files and I'm wondering how would i go about splitting an xml file into two files using vb.

The main issue I'm having with the xml file is that its too large to upload. I'm hoping splitting it into two will solve my issue. For example an xml with a file size of 34kb when split into two will give 2 xml files of 17KB each.

```
   Dim doc As XDocument 
   doc = XDocument.Load("XMLSplit/Directory.xml")
   ' 1 grab the file size 
   ' 2 divide file size by 2 
   ' 3 find half way of the xml file 
   ' 4 split into two 
   ' 5 save split files as Directory1xml and Directory2.xml
```

Directory.xml

```
<Directory>
  <Person>
    <Name> John / </Name>
    <age> 24 </age>
    <DOB>
      <year> 1990 </year>
      <month> 03 </month>
      <date> 23 </date>
    </DOB>
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name> Jane / </Name>
    <age> 21 </age>
    <DOB>
      <year> 1993 </year>
      <month> 04 </month>
      <date> 25 </date>
    </DOB>
  </Person>
</Directory>
```

Comment: How do you want to "split" it?  Can't you just save out whatever elements you need into an alternate file?

Comment: that's what i'm hoping to do with the program - split the xml file and then save it as 2 xml files

Comment: Where do you want to split it? Do you want an xml file for each `<person>`? Or do you want to save just one?

Comment: Do you want to *split* on every `Person` node (produce two separate files for each person)?

Comment: I'm hoping for the program to take in the file - get the file size divide by 2 then split the file - That way the two files will make 1 Directory.xml file

Comment: IMO you need to review your problem and your solution and maybe rewrite the question. Let's say your file has 3 Persons ... will the splitting by size make sense then - the data of the person in the middle will be half in file1 half in file2. Do you want this?

Comment: "I'm hoping for the program to take in the file - get the file size divide by 2 then split the file - That way the two files will make 1 Directory.xml file" -- apologies, but that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I just want to split the file into two, the xml file I gave above is an example -> the issue I'm having the xml file is to large to upload so splitting it into two would help. lets say the xml file size is 34kb splitting it into 2 would make xml1 and xml2 17kb each allowing the file to easily upload

Comment: One possible approach would be to convert the file to binary (byte array?), split it in parts, upload every part separately, and on the remote site *build* the file together. Splitting the XML structure is not a good option. In such cases *raw* data is better and easier to deal with.

Comment: Hmm... okay - I'll play around it hopefully i can come up with a solution to split the file

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to treat the file as XML. Handling the file as plain text should be alright. You can use the [String.Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to take parts of the string. A simple algorithm for splitting can look like this:

- define how long each part would be - **n**
- take **n** characters from the string starting from position **p** (initially 0)
- move forward by increasing **p** with **n**
- loop until end of the string is not reached

One possible solution to split the string into equal parts (in this case 2 parts) can be implemented like this (in this case the length to take would be half of the string length = two equal parts):

```
private function chunkify(byval source as string, byval length as integer) as List(of string)
    dim chunks = new List(of string)
    dim pos = 0
    while (pos < source.Length)
        dim toTake = length
        if not (source.Length - pos) > length then
            toTake = source.Length - pos
        end if
        chunks.Add(source.Substring(pos, toTake))
        pos = pos + length
    end while
    return chunks
end function
```

Call the `chunkify` on the string with the length you want each part to have (your parts are in a list containing strings):

```
dim content = File.ReadAllText("d:\\xml.xml")
dim chunks = chunkify(content, content.Length / 2)
for each chunk in chunks
    Console.WriteLine(chunk)
next chunk
```

The output with your content is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Directory>
  <Person>
    <Name> John / </Name>
    <age> 24 </age>
    <DOB>
      <year> 1990 </year>
      <month> 03 </month>
      <date> 23 </date>
    </DOB>
' here is the new line from the Console.WriteLine
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name> Jane / </Name>
    <age> 21 </age>
    <DOB>
      <year> 1993 </year>
      <month> 04 </month>
      <date> 25 </date>
    </DOB>
  </Person>
</Directory>
```

I would suggest you to convert your XML to bytes and then split the bytes into equal parts (in this case, take the `length / 2`), because it could be suitable to transfer. One possible solution for the split function could look like this:

```
function chunkify(byval source as byte(), byval length as integer) as List(Of byte())
    ' result list containing all parts
    dim chunks = new List(of byte())
    ' the first chunk of content
    dim chunk = source.Take(length).ToArray()
    do 'loop as long there is something in the array
        chunks.Add(chunk)
        ' remove already read content
        source = source.Skip(length).ToArray()
        ' is there more to take?
        chunk = source.Take(length).ToArray()
    loop while (chunk.Length > 0)
    return chunks
end function
```

The usage looks like this:

```
' read all bytes
dim content = File.ReadAllBytes("d:\\xml.xml")
' split into equal parts
dim chunks = chunkify(content, content.Length / 2)
' print / handle each part
for each chunk in chunks

    Console.WriteLine(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(chunk))
    Console.WriteLine("==================================")
next chunk
```

Using your example XML the output after the split is as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Directory>
  <Person>
    <Name> John / </Name>
    <age> 24 </age>
    <DOB>
      <year> 1990 </year>
      <month> 03 </month>
      <date> 23 </date>
    </DOB>
==================================
  </Person>
  <Person>
    <Name> Jane / </Name>
    <age> 21 </age>
    <DOB>
      <year> 1993 </year>
      <month> 04 </month>
      <date> 25 </date>
    </DOB>
  </Person>
</Directory>
==================================
```